# Differences between standard java web application directory structure and directory structure generated by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am learning Java EE,  and The book I'm using says that the standard directory structure for a webapp is:

```
MyApp/:Here, the view of my App (Resources that can be directly requested)
      .xhtml Files
      .jsp Files
MyApp/WEB-INF:
      web.xml file for deployment instructions of the webapp
MyApp/WEB-INF/lib: 
      Here, the external jars (API, Frameworks,etc) used by the  webapp
MyApp/WEB-INF/classes:
     .class Files (Compiled classes for my webapp)
```

That's work perfectly. But, now, I am starting to work with eclipse for JEE. I created a dynamic web project. And the generated structure directory for the project is:

```
MyApp/
MyApp/build
MyApp/src 
MyApp/WebContent
MyApp/WebContent/META-INF
MyApp/WebContent/WEB-INF
MyApp/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
```

Yes, The above also work. But, Why eclipse does not follow the specification ? Does the server (Apache tomcat) know about various types of directory structures? Where can I learn them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After build your project it will also create same things @Matias W.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on your web application project in `eclipse`, and select `Properties`, one of the section available is `Deployment Assembly`. Through this section, you can give Eclipse custom information about which files should be deployed to `Tomcat` directory.